# Domino Designer: finding hidden @Prompt

Tags: debugging, lotus-domino, prompt

Here comes an embarrassing question:

For debug purposes I work with `@Prompt` statements (because there is no debugger for formula language in Domino Designer).

But now I have the problem, that there always appears a message box when opening a specific form called "PartnerContact".

[image: (CONTACT_NOMINATION is the name of a field)]
(CONTACT_NOMINATION is the name of a field)

I was looking up the whole code of this form (and each form to which I did some modifications) manually as well as with the included search

[image]

I performed the search with each of the following search strings:
`@Prompt`
`Msgbox`
`Messagebox`
`System.out`

But with non of them I had any search result.

I despair of this message box. Do you have any hints where this damn box could possibly hide?

Answer (score 2):

For the future. There is a very useful option: `File->Application->Design Synopsis...`. Add all design elements and search through all of their properties and code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it.

One of the fields in the view is a `Dialog List`. The available choices are computed under `field properties` ->  `controls` -> `Choices`-> `Use formula for choices`

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of issues here to check. The Design Synopsis that @pstr mentions should work, unless it is corruption or duplicated design element.

First try using the search in designer, rather then form itself.

[image: Search Icon]

Search for "CONTACT_NOMINATION" and "PartnerContact".

[image: search dialog]

This will display the results in DXL format, so you can check the source, or manually go to the related objects yourself.

another option is to right click on the related design element and "Edit with DXL". It will allow you to see any corruption, for example fields which are not rendering in the UI.

[image: edit with dxl]

Lastly you can try using NotesPeek as it can easily check for design duplication. You can pick it up at the following link.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686

Answer (score 0):

FYI, have a look to TeamStudo Analyzer - very good and simple product to search (and find ;-) ) everything in your design elements. (PS : it's not free and i dont work for TeamStudio !)